# Where are the “range” and “functional” aspects of ActivityPub properties defined?

Tags: activity-streams, mastodon, activitypub

[Activity Vocabulary](https://www.w3.org/TR/activitystreams-vocabulary/#type) has tables which indicate several aspects (meta-properties?) of each property defined in Activity Streams 2.0. These aspects include:

- functional — is it single-value, or not?
- range — indicates the type of value the property term can have
- subproperty of — meaning that the term is a specialization of the referenced term

Here's [a good example](https://www.w3.org/TR/activitystreams-vocabulary/#dfn-actor).

I haven't been able to find something like this for the properties added by [ActivityPub](https://www.w3.org/TR/activitypub/).

For example, take `following`. The ActivityPub Recommendation says:

> A link to an [ActivityStreams] collection of the actors that this actor is following; see 5.4 Following Collection
> ...
> Every actor SHOULD have a following collection. This is a list of everybody that the actor has followed, added as a side effect. The following collection MUST be either an OrderedCollection or a Collection and MAY be filtered on privileges of an authenticated user or as appropriate when no authentication is given.

And that's just about it. Based on the above, I would have thought the range was `Collection` (like it is for `replies`), but looking at the examples and data returned by a Mastodon instance, I see the `following` property being set like this:

```json
"following": "https://example.org/users/johndoe/following",
```

So what's the correct range for the `following` property?

Also, can an Object have multiple values for `following`, or is it "functional"?

In general, where are these aspects of all of the ActivityPub properties defined?